# Neo4j Many To Many relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have three nodes : OrganizationA,OrganizationB,OrganizationC.

And the realtionships are "Organization support each other". 
i.e

```
[OragizationA]-[:supports]->[OrganizationB] ,
[OragizationB]-[:supports]->[OrganizationA]... and so on :
```

I am implementing a Cypher query (Neo4j):

```
Match (org:Organization)
create (org)-[:support]->(org)
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: From your question, absolutely no clear goal or problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there is no benefit of having (a)-[:SUPPORTS]->(b) and (b)-[:SUPPORTS]->(a) at the same time, because you can traverse relationships in both directions, so usually one is enough. Nevertheless, here are 2 answers:

```
MATCH (org1:Organization),(org2:Organization)
WHERE org1 <> org2
CREATE (org1)-[:SUPPORTS]->(org2)
```

and

```
MATCH (org1:Organization),(org2:Organization)
CREATE (org1)-[:SUPPORTS]->(org2)
```

Second one will create also (org1)-[:SUPPORTS]->(org1) if that's what you want :)